# How to reset initialization while calling method of same class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core

Following i have a worker class and there is a foreach.
Inside the forach there is service call which can be  ***GetX(), GetY() ...***
as implementation, I have to re-initialize the Api client based on the parameter, is there pattern to avoid ***_aService.SetApiClient(p)*** Line?

```
public class Worker
    {
        private readonly IAService _aService;

        public Worker(IAService entryPointService)
        {
            _aService = entryPointService;
        }

        protected void ExecuteAsync()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                new List<string>() { "x", "y", "z" }.ForEach(p =>
                {
                    _aService.SetApiClient(p);
                    _aService.GetX();
                    // OR _aService.GetY(),_aService.GetYZ();//
                });

            }
        }
}
        public class AService : IAService
        {
            private GoogleApiClient _googleApiClient;
            public AService(GoogleApiClient apiClient)
            {
                _googleApiClient = apiClient;
            }

            public void SetApiClient(string param)
            {
                _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient(new AuthProvider (param));
            }
            public string GetX()
            {
                return _googleApiClient.CallX();
            }
        }

        public interface IAService
        {
            void SetApiClient(string param);
            string GetX();
        }

        public interface IGoogleApiClient
        {
            string CallX();
            string CallY();
            string CallZ();
        }  

public class GoogleApiClient : IGoogleApiClient
    {
        private AuthProvider _param;
        public GoogleApiClient(AuthProvider param)
        {
            _param = param;
        }
        public string CallX()
        {
            return DoSomeCal("X", _param);
        }
        public string CallY()
        {
            return DoSomeCal("Y", _param);
        }
        public string CallZ()
        {
            return DoSomeCal("Z", _param)
        }
    }
```

please note that string list values can be any thing

Comment: Are you asking how to map a string value to a specific method call? The example is a little unclear, but it sounds like you want to call `GetX()` if `p == "x"`, or `GetY()` if `p == "y"`.

Comment: @RufusL  As a example, if p == "x" api client(GoogleApiClient) is needed to be re-initialized, not the GetX()

Answer (score 0):

Your api client really doesn't need to hold state.(private field}) It is a service / gateway class. Rather just pass param into the methods e.g.GetX(string param}.